# Do some GPUs or drivers lack some of the glsl built-in functions?

Tags: opengl, glsl, gpu

I'm trying to perform a log during my rendering on an Intel X3100 under Linux (using the default Ubuntu driver). The code looks something like as follows:

```
vec4 frag_color;
frag_color.rgb = log(frag_value.rgb);
frag_color.a = frag_value.a
gl_FragColor = frag_color;
```

where frag_value is derived from a texture lookup. Now, I can set the texture such that the log of `frag_value` should give a sensible answer (i.e, it's in a sensible range to give a frag_color 0.0->1.0), but it always renders as black (so I assume it's just setting it to zero). Of course, I can verify I'm sensibly setting `frag_value` by removing the log (and setting the frag_value texture to be in the range 0.0->1.0), which does what I expect, and multiplication and other trivial operations work fine.

My question is, is this expected behaviour? Am I missing something? Are some GPUs or drivers lacking the some built in functions (e.g. sqrt seems to not work either)?

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong, but isn't OpenGL supposed to emulate whatever is missing in the hardware? I mean, the driver of the graphics card should be able to handle this even if the hardware doesn't implement it. Isn't that correct?

Comment: @Shahbaz - yes it should fall back to software rendering.

Comment: So it sounds like either i'm doing something wrong, or something isn't working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it:

Texture uploads are usually clamped to the range 0.0->1.0 (despite what might be inferred from the internal format type name), so of course `log` is not going to give anything useful. Full range floats were introduced with [ARB_texture_float](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_float.txt), which extends the internal types to include full range floats, such as LUMINANCE_ALPHA32F_ARB. Using that solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure color components are in the 0.0-1.0 range for regular non-float textures.

I'm also pretty sure `gl_FragColor` components are clamped to the 0.0-1.0 range by default.

log(x) for 0 < x < 1 is negative.

Comment: Sorry, I just clarified this. I did actually set frag_value to be a number that yielded a log in the range 0->1 (and then set it to be something else when rendering directly). Unless it's clamping the texture values for me! I've requested it store it internally as a float, but I'm not overly confident it's not doing something nefarious.

Comment: I can confirm that it appears that texture_value is not a full range float (clamping 0->1). I'll investigate further as to whether this is my problem.

Answer (score 2):

> Do some GPUs or drivers lack **some** of the glsl built-in functions?

Yes. noise functions aren't properly implemented anywhere - non-functional on NVidia, massive performance drop or non-functional on ATI (were this way last time I checked).